# SchemaDumper generating different output on Mac & Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We're using activerecord 5.1.4 in our project.
When running migrations the SchemaDumper generates different output on different colleagues machines. Some are using Linux others using Mac.

We're all running the same postgres version 9.6

For example Macs generate:

`create_table "appliances", force: cascade do |t|
  t.string   "brand"
  t.integer  "property_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
end`

Linux creates:

`create_table "appliances", id: :serial, force: cascade do |t|
  t.string "brand"
  t.integer "property_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end`

Linux output seems to have `id: :serial` and it doesn't pad columns to align.

It means we're constantly bouncing changes to `schema.rb` in version control
Why would the output be different?

Comment: I tried replicating , but didn't got anything . Can you post the command you are using to generate the migration ?

Comment: Did u use this command - rake db:schema:dump ?

Comment: I'm using `rake db:migrate` when running migrations which regenerates the schema. I've just tried `rake db:schema:dump` and it produces the same thing.